# What does the :8 mean in Webpack's output variables. filename: [name][contenthash:8]?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm configuring Webpacks output and i have run into some examples which have this unusual
syntax added on the end.

```
output: {
    filename: '[name][fullHash:8].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name][fullHash:8].bundle.js',
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    publicPath: "/",
},
```

Ok now you see the :8's after fullhash? what extra feature does it provide? My first guess was UTF-8??? But that's just a stab in the dark.

Comment: maybe it is slicing the first 8 characters of the full hash?

Comment: Ahhh, thats a great idea, i'll test it out right now.n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from a quick little search in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/), I found this one section which talks about it

> The length of hashes ([hash], [contenthash] or [chunkhash]) can be specified using [hash:16] (defaults to 20). Alternatively, specify output.hashDigestLength to configure the length globally.

So going by that, it would probably mean that `[fullHash:8]` would produce a hash of length 8, which I suppose I would advice against, and would be better off to keep it at the default of 20 (by just removing the `:8`).

Comment: i was just going to ask you to post your answer. Great job and thank you